# Scanner candle stick patterns

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am inexperienced in pine script. Looking to develop a custom scanner.

I am looking for specific candle stick patterns on all nominated time frames like week,days,hours and minutes.

Definitions:

```
Rally candles are green and go up in price - 

 2. Rally candles are red and go down in price -
 3. Doji candles as defined in investopedia regardless of colour and with a body
```

The two candle stick patterns are first :

```
Increase in price ( green rally candle ) then a doji candle either green or red in colour

     Decrease in price ( red rally candle ) then a doji candle either green or red in colour
```

Then the second pattern

```
Increase in price ( green rally candle ) then a pull back candle red in colour where the opening price of the pullback candle does not exceed 50% of the prior green rally candle closing price

 Decrease in price ( red rally candle ) then a pull back candle green in colour where the closing price of the pullback candle does not exceed 50% of the prior red rally candle opening price
```

Can TV create a table with columns of nominated time frames stated above?

Cheers

Comment: this is code I am already using for find such patterns:

Comment: //@version=5
indicator("RBR/DBD Alert", overlay=true)
 
 
previous_candle_035_down = math.max(open[1], close[1]) - ((math.max(open[1], close[1]) - math.min(open[1], close[1])) * 0.35)
plot(previous_candle_035_down, color=color.red, display=display.none)
previous_candle_035_up = math.min(open[1], close[1]) + ((math.max(open[1], close[1]) - math.min(open[1], close[1])) * 0.35)
plot(previous_candle_035_up, color=color.green, display=display.none)

Comment: previous_is_breakdown_down = close < previous_candle_035_down and open < close //open[1] > ema_close[1] and close[1] < ema_close[1] and 
previous_is_breakdown_up = close > previous_candle_035_up and open > close //open[1] < ema_close[1] and close[1] > ema_close[1] and 
 
 
alertcondition(previous_is_breakdown_down, title='DBD', message='DBD')
alertcondition(previous_is_breakdown_up, title='RBR', message='RBR')
 
plotchar(previous_is_breakdown_down, char='D')
plotchar(previous_is_breakdown_up, char='R')